# Are there any references/samples to use dataflow in batch mode for reading the data from Pub sub and writing to BQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

we have a use case to write to data into two tables one table has complete records, and the other table with only the latest records and the table name is also dynamic

**Example Dataset:**

```
row1: {"table_name": "inv" , "rec": {id:1, name: test, version: v1, createtime: 2022-01-10 11:20:13, updatetetime: 2022 -01-10 11:20:13}}
row2: {"table_name": "inv" , "rec":{id:2, name: test1, version: v1, createtime: 2022-01-11 11:20:13, updatetetime: 2022 -01-11 11:20:13}}
row3: {"table_name": "inv" , "rec":{id:1, name: test, version: v2, createtime: 2022-01-10 11:20:13, updatetetime: 2022 -01-11 11:20:13}}
row4: {"table_name": "inv" , "rec":{id:1, name: test, version: v3, createtime: 2022-01-10 11:20:13, updatetetime: 2022 -01-12 11:20:13}}
row5: {"table_name": "inv" , "rec":{id:1, name: test, version: v4, createtime: 2022-01-10 11:20:13, updatetetime: 2022 -01-13 11:20:13}}
row6: {"table_name": "inv" , "rec":{id:1, name: test, version: v5, createtime: 2022-01-10 11:20:13, updatetetime: 2022 -01-14 11:20:13}}
```

So the history table contains all the records from the pub-sub, and the main table only has row2 and row6 as they are the latest records based on the id.

Comment: Batch mode with pubsub source?

Comment: yes, that's correct @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a design issue: How to batch, I mean process a set of data, by reading from an unbounding data source?

Indeed, PubSub is a message queueing product, there is no beginning, no end. So, batch makes no sense to that type of source. You can process the data per time window, and batch process the messages received in that window, but the whole processing is always streaming.

Comment: Agreed! I am not sure about the terminology but I am expecting a mini-batch for processing data every 1 min or so using window functions and looking for samples related to it

Comment: Don't you have enough example in the documentation? https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Comment: this helps thanks